# How to move a wiki to other project in Azure DevOps

Tags: import, azure-devops, export, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

I need move the wiki from a project to other.

We are using Azure DevOps and both projects are in the same organization.

I haven't seen any tools neither any option in DevOps.

Comment: Hi, how about Shayki's solution? Does it could help you achieve what you want? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you are still facing some issues please leave a comment so we can still help you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The wikis are git repositories, you can clone the both repos, copy the data from the current project to the second project, commit all and push.

How to get the clone url? here:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Good idea. I have resolved my issue with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The Azure DevOps wiki is a git repo, but to expand on the other answer, with the subsequent step.

There are other methods on the net about migrating wikis and the problem with attachments, but this method migrates all pages, attachments and links.

1. On the **source** Azure DevOps, browse to the root of the wiki page `board -> wiki` and click `clone wiki`

[image: clone wiki]

2. Copy the git url and the credentials

[image: clone repo]

3. On the **target** Azure DevOps, browse to `Repos -> Files`
4. Choose `import a repository`

[image: Import git button]

5. In the pop up window, type in the Clone URL, tick `Requires authentication` then the username and password.

[image: Import a git repo]

5. This takes a 'short' amount of time depending on how large your wiki is. For my wiki of 200 text-heavy pages, it took about 1 second. but Azure DevOps will send you an email confirming when it is complete.

Note: this process works migrating from one Azure DevOps organisation to another.

Answer (score 3):

Below answers are incomplete.

1. Clone the wiki of source - Make sure to copy the giturl, username and password.
2. On target project go to Repos > Files > Import Repository
   User repository fields from step 1
3. On target project, go to Overview > Wiki > Publish code as wiki
4. Select repository settings from step 2, folder as / (root folder) and add wiki name.
5. Publish. Wait for sometime and done.

Refer link : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002219/in-azure-devops-is-there-an-easy-way-to-copy-a-wiki-from-one-repo-to-another)