# In Azure DevOps, is there an easy way to copy a wiki from one repo to another?

Tags: azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

I see there is a "clone wiki" link but I don't know if it's possible to import a cloned wiki into another repo. What we're doing is moving our repo from our own Azure account to a client's Azure account so the wiki will be lost and I'd rather not have to manually copypasta all the wiki pages...

Comment: Not worth an answer, but I've answered this on this SO page. I've answered this on this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58435460/how-to-move-a-wiki-to-other-project-in-azure-devops

Answer (score 7):

> If it's possible to import a cloned wiki into another repo.

Of course, yes.

For our backend, **Wikis** are **GIT** repository.

So, you could use **Clone Wiki** button to easily clone one wiki repo into your local system or copy paste the markdown files into a new repo. According to your description, what you want should be the latter.

---

- **Step1:** Click **Import repository** and then fill the link you got from the Clone Wiki button in the Clone URL box.

[image]

- **Step2:** Then, switch to **Wiki** tab and go [**Publish code as wiki**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/publish-repo-to-wiki?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#publish-a-git-repository-to-a-wiki).

[image]

- **Step3:** Now, you could **select the folder** which contain the Markdown files and **name** the new wiki repository.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, interesting... Where can I find the "import repository" button in step 1?

Comment: @ekolis, the same place when you want to import a repos from ourtside: https://imgur.com/a/sdvoG51

Comment: Oh, I don't  have that option there; must be a permissions issue. Guess I'll have to either ask for permission to create a repo or ask someone else to set this up...

Comment: @ekolis Hope its all work fine on your side after the permission allowed

Comment: @ekolis, just want to confirm any process on this issue? could you achieve this wiki clone successfully now?

Comment: Sorry, I have yet to get permissions to import a repository or find someone who can who is willing to do this for me. Is there any other way I can do this? Maybe create my own repository and import it from there? I have access to the "publish code as wiki" button....

Comment: @ekolis Of course sure. You could import it into yourself repos by using the token. Then you can visit the publish wiki feature without any limitation.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any way to create a new repo. Not sure if I'm missing something obvious or if I just don't have permission to do so. I can create a new organization, oddly enough...

Comment: @ekolis As I know, this should relevant with permission limited such as edit repos. I’d better suggest you apply this in your private org and project which you has completed operated permission.